# iOS7 unrecognised selector, unknown class

Tags: ios, ios7, unrecognized-selector

I've been trying to get to the bottom of this exception.  I have a UITable view, and every now and then (approx 1 in 10) refreshes I get a crash with the following message.

```
-[_UICascadingTextStorage _setIndexBarWidth:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15da4110
2014-06-09 14:05:19.272 FastFarmV01[2290:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UICascadingTextStorage _setIndexBarWidth:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15da4110'
```

Any one have any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Check that your UICascadingTextStorage is not to nil when you try make a call.

Comment: Look at the stack.  See what operation you're doing on what sort of object.  Check the setup parms for that object.

Comment: what are you using, `ARC` or `MRR`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like setIndexBarWidth doesnt exist in UICascadingTextStorage class.

This method name doesn't appear anywhere in this class 
https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/_UICascadingTextStorage.h

Are you sure you didn't want to use another method?